# How to design a python class which will behave like root classes

Tags: python, class, operator-overloading

> EDIT:
>
> As mentioned in the responses, search keyword for this question is
>   "assignment operator overloading in python".

I want to construct a class which will behave like an integer or string class behaves. Something like that:

```
x = "hello"
x.upper() # says "HELLO"


y = MyClass()
y = 3
y = 5
print(y) # will print 5
y.previous_value() # will yield 3
```

How can I build a class that behaves like this?

### Edit:

The closest hack is this for now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6012807/1952991

Comment: you need to learn [Operator overloading in Python](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/operatoroverloading1.txt)

Comment: It's not clear how much you've done or know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024646/is-it-possible-to-overload-python-assignment

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024646/is-it-possible-to-overload-python-assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve this:

```
y = MyClass()
y = 3
y = 5
y.previous_value() # will yield 3
```

Assignment in Python rebinds the name to another object. When you do `y = 3`, `y` is now a name for the integer 3, not for an instance of `MyClass`. This behaviour doesn't depend on the old RHS at all, and can't be intercepted by it without *deep* magic (you could *possibly* do something with context managers). The instance of `MyClass` that y used to refer to has no knowledge that y no longer refers to it (or that it did in the first place); and even if it did, `y.previous_value()` would call a method on the *int*, not on the `MyClass` instance.

The closest you can do is to play with `__setitem__`. This is the hook that Python calls when you do something like this:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
x[2] = 5
```

the second line translates to `x.__setitem__(2, 5)`. Using this, you can play fun games like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.values = []

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        self.value.append(value)

    def previousvalue(self):
        return self.values[-2]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.values[-1])

x = MyClass()
x[:] = 5
x[:] = 6
print(x.previousvalue())
```

Note that you *need* the `[]` to trigger `__setitem__`, and it needs to have a value - this can be any object, since it is ignored, so I use an empty slice. The fact that you need to jump through syntactic hoops like this should be a big indicator that you should rethink why you want to do this - there is almost certainly a better way to achieve your goal.