# Reference of a single numpy array element

Tags: python, numpy

Lets say I have a numpy array like

```
x = np.arange(10)
```

is it somehow possible to create a reference to a single element i.e.

```
y = create_a_reference_to(x[3])
y = 100 
print x
[  0   1   2 100   4   5   6   7   8   9]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't create a reference to a single element, but you can get a **view** over that single element:

```
>>> x = numpy.arange(10)
>>> y = x[3:4]
>>> y[0] = 100
>>> x
array([0, 1, 2, 100, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

The reason you can't do the former is that everything in python is a reference. By doing `y = 100`, you're modifying what `y` points to - not it's value.

If you really want to, you can [get that behaviour on instance attributes by using properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6012925/1595865). Note this is only possible because the python data model [specifies additional operations while accessing class attributes](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access) - *it's not possible to get this behaviour for variables*.

Comment: Is it maybe possible to wrap my variable up in a class to get this behavior ?

Answer (score 2):

**No you cannot do that**, and that is **by design**.

Numpy arrays are of type `numpy.ndarray`. Individual items in it can be accessed with `numpy.ndarray.item` which does "copy an element of an array to a standard Python scalar and return it".

I'm guessing numpy returns a copy instead of direct reference to the element **to prevent mutability of numpy items outside of numpy's own implementation**.

Just as a thoughtgame, let's assume this wouldn't be the case and you would be allowed to get reference to individual items. Then what would happen if: numpy was in the midle of calculation and you altered an individual intime in another thread?

Comment: Are you sure about this ? For example it is possible to create a view of an array i.e. y = x[4:6] (see answer above). If I manipulate this view I also have changes in the original array.

Comment: @jrsm jsalonen's point is that you can't sidestep numpy. Using a view, you'll be [calling numpy behind-the-scenes every time you assign to a element of the view](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set__).

Answer (score 0):

@goncalopp gives a correct answer, but there are a few variations that will achieve similar effects.

All of the notations shown below are able to reference a single element while still returning a view:

```
x = np.arange(10)
two_index_method = [None] * 10
scalar_element_method = [None] * 10
expansion_method = [None] * 10
for i in range(10):
    two_index_method[i] = x[i:i+1]
    scalar_element_method[i] = x[..., i]  # x[i, ...] works, too
    expansion_method[i] = x[:, np.newaxis][i]  # np.newaxis == None

two_index_method[5]  # Returns a length 1 numpy.ndarray, shape=(1,)
# >>> array([5])
scalar_element_method[5]  # Returns a numpy scalar, shape = ()
# >>> array(5)
expansion_method[5]  # Returns a length 1 numpy.ndarray, shape=(1,)
# >>> array([5])
x[5] = 42  # Change the value in the original `ndarray`
x
# >>> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 42, 6, 7, 8, 9])  # The element has been updated
# All methods presented here are correspondingly updated:
two_index_method[5], scalar_element_method[5], expansion_method[5]
# >>> (array([42]), array(42), array([42]))
```

Since the object in `scalar_element_method` is a dimension zero scalar, attempting to reference the element contained within the `ndarray` via `element[0]` will return an `IndexError`.  For a scalar `ndarray`, `element[()]` can be used to reference the element contained within the numpy scalar.  This method can also be used for assignment to a length-1 `ndarray`, but has the unfortunate side effect that it does not dereference a length-1 `ndarray` to a python scalar.  Fortunately, there is a single method, `element.item()`, that can be used (for dereferencing only) to obtain the value regardless of whether the element is a length one `ndarray` or a scalar `ndarray`:

```
scalar_element_method[5][0]  # This fails
# >>> IndexError: too many indices for array
scalar_element_method[5][()]  # This works for scalar `ndarray`s
# >>> 42
scalar_element_method[5][()] = 6
expansion_method[5][0]  # This works for length-1 `ndarray`s
# >>> 6
expansion_method[5][()]  # Doesn't return a python scalar (or even a numpy scalar)
# >>> array([6])
expansion_method[5][()] = 8  # But can still be used to change the value by reference
scalar_element_method[5].item()  # item() works to dereference all methods
# >>> 8
expansion_method[5].item()
# >>> [i]8
```

TLDR; You can create a single-element view `v` with `v = x[i:i+1]`, `v = x[..., i]`, or `v = x[:, None][i]`.  While different setters and getters work with each method, you can always assign values with `v[()]=new_value`, and you can always retrieve a python scalar with `v.item()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.newaxis` when indexing an element, so that instead of returning a Python scalar, numpy returns a reference to an array element. Below is a minimum working example.

```
>>> arr = np.asarray([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> arr
array([0, 1, 2, 3])

>>> element2 = arr[2, np.newaxis]
>>> element2
array([2])

# Changing the element will modify the original array
>>> element2[:] = 100
>>> element2
array([100])

>>> arr
array([  0,   1, 100,   3])
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT -- according to jared's comment below, `None` can also be used in place of `np.newaxis`.

Comment: Also, `np.newaxis` and `None` are equivalent, so this could be done as `element2 = arr[2, None]`.